# Submitting same information that is already created

Tags: javascript

I have form validation code which notifies when the `EmployeeNo` and `EngagementID` have already been created. It should work like this: when you have an `EmployeeNo` with `0507` and an `EngagementID` with `13`, it should not create a duplicate. The error should be, **Engagement already exists on that username**. Can you please help me?

```
function validateForm() {
    var a = $("#EngagementID").val();
    var b = $("#EmployeeNo").val();

    if (a > 0 ) {
        $.notify("Engagement already exists on that username.", "error");
        return false;
    }   else  {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI kindly include everything you got in JS., and also if may, your HTML content.

Comment: that is my js for the validate form the other functions are not related to that.  My form is inside the modal.

Comment: alright anyway where is data coming form to compare if the current employee was created? (Storage of created employee that contains employeeNo and employeeID)

Comment: in the database.It should be like this, if you have a current employee with the same engagement id the engagement id should not be created again in the same employee.

Comment: Ok, I believe this can be done through server-side validation and not in client side since you say that the data comes from your database, so if you'll be doing it in server-side scripts it goes like this. As a new engagement about to be submitted, you first try to select (look) such data in your database, (ex. engagement name) if the query has returned result it means it already existed so there you can return an error, else you can now "Insert" the data.

Comment: soI need to use ajax? and put the query inside?

Comment: that depends on you though, btw what do you use for server-side scripting?

Comment: I'm using php. I don't know if my ajax query is correct. function validateForm() {

        $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#save').fadeOut(300);

            $.ajax({
                url: 
                type:
                data:
                sucess:
                 if () {

                 } else () {

                 }
            })
        }
    }

Comment: Hi you can use this for your reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562595/execute-javascript-after-ajax-response-has-been-rendered